# Bernoulli experiment - hypothesis testing with specific scenario

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Let's consider null hypothesis that we want to examine, that probability of success is smaller than $\frac 1 2$ in Bernouli distribution. We also have independent sample of $20$ observations: $x_1, x_2, ..., x_{20}$ from this distribution. We are going to reject the null hypothesis if any only if amount of observed successes in this experiment is 11 or lower. I want to calculate power of this test:

**My work so far**

$$X \sim \text{Bernouli}(\theta)$$
$$H_0:\theta < \frac 1 2$$

Function $\phi$ is a function that takes value $1$ when we reject null hypothesis and value $0$ when we do not reject it. In our example:

$$\phi(x_1, x_2, ..., x_{20}) = \begin{cases}
1& \text{with probability} \;{20 \choose 11} \theta^{11} (1 - \theta)^{9}\\
0& \text{with probability} \;1 - {20 \choose 11} \theta^{11} (1 - \theta)^{9}
\end{cases}$$

Then power of the test is given as $E_\theta[\phi(x_1,...,x_{20})] = {20 \choose 11} \theta^{11} (1 - \theta)^{9} $

Am I correct with my calculations?

Comment: You may have some typos in your question:  your null hypothesis seems to be that the probability of success is small (usually this would not be a *strict* inequality for a null hypothesis) but you will reject this if the number of successes is small (sure this would be what you expect?), though the rejection region (the sum of binomial probabilities, not a single value) seems to have a probability over $50\%$

Answer (score 0):

*Comment:* As @Henry comments, something must be wrong with the statement
of your question. Maybe I can help you formulate a more
reasonable version of it.

If you are testing $H_0: p = 1/2$ against $H_a: p < 1/2,$
then it might make sense to reject $H_0$ if you see $x \le 6$ Successes in $n = 20$ trials. Then the significance
level of your test would be about 6%. [Because of the
discreteness of the binomial distribution, it is not
possible to have a (nonrandomized) test at *exactly* the 5% level.] Computation using R:

```
pbinom(6, 20, .5)
[1] 0.05765915
```

In order to find the power of my proposed test with critical value $c = 6,$ you would have to specify a *particular*
alternative success probability $p_a.$

Perhaps you want to find the
probability of rejecting $H_0$ with my test if the true
success probability is $p_a = 1/4.$ Then you need to find
$P(X \le 6 \,|\, p=1/4) = 0.7858,$ which is the power of my test against the alternative $p_a = 1/4.$

```
pbinom(6, 20, 1/4)
[1] 0.7857819
```

Taking another approach, let's look at the exact binomial test procedure `binom.test` in R:  With $x = 11$ successes is $n=20$ trials, that test gives P-value $0.7483.$  To test (nearly) at
the 5% level, you would want to see a P-value near $0.05 = 5\%.$

```
binom.test(11, 20, p=.5, alt = "less")

        Exact binomial test

data:  11 and 20
number of successes = 11, number of trials = 20, 
 p-value = 0.7483
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is less than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.0000000 0.7413494
sample estimates:
 probability of success 
                   0.55
```

The bottom line is that it would make no sense to reject $H_0: p=1/2$ in favor of $H_a: p < 1/2,$ when the estimated success
probability is $\hat p = x/p = 0.55 > 1/2.$

*Notes:*

(1) *Power curve.* It is possible to make a 'power curve', showing powers of my test proposed above for various alternative values of $p_a.$ Red lines show the
power for the particular alternative $p_a = 1/4,$ discussed above.

```
p.alt = seq(.1, .49, by=.01)
pwr = pbinom(6, 20, p.alt)
hdr="Power Curve for Proposed Test"
plot(p.alt, ylim=0:1, pwr, type="l", main=hdr)
 abline(v=.25, col="red")
 abline(h=.7858, col="red")
```

[image]

(2) *Another reasonable scenario and test.* If $n = 33,$ then it makes sense to use $c=11$ as
the critical value for a left-sided test at the 4% level, which would have power about 90% against the alternative
value $p_a = 1/4.$ [I will let you fill in the gaps on
this proposed test, based on the following computations in R.]

```
pbinom(11, 33, .5)
[1] 0.04007166
pbinom(11, 33, .25)
[1] 0.9012785
```